# JSON response in localStorage

Tags: javascript, json, string, local-storage

My JSON response is a key value pair.

```
 {"category":[{"id":1,"name":"Merc"},{"id":2,"name":"BMW"}]}
```

After I parse the response like

```
 var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
```

I need to store in `localStorage`

```
 localStorage.setItem('carList', cars);
```

Now this cars should be saved as comma separated key,value pair...how to do it?

```
 //1,Merc,2,BMW
```

Comment: Where'd `cars` come from? You parsed your JSON into `data`.

Comment: If you wanted to store a string like `1,Merc,2,BMW`, then you have to create it explicitly. But storing it as JSON is better.

Comment: @FelixKling If I add as JSON string like localStorage.setItem("str",JSON). Will it save str as `{"category":[{"id":1,"name":"Merc"},{"id":2,"name":"BMW"}]}
` ? Then I have to parse it again is it?

Comment: @oneofthelions: Yes. It depends on what you want to do with the data in the end, but I think it would be easier since you already have the logic to process the JSON. If you use a comma-separated string, you have to create another function to parse it.

Answer (score 2):

I hope following link [HTML5 localstorage to store JSON objects](http://samcroft.co.uk/2013/using-localstorage-to-store-json/) will help you for storing json response in localStorage..

It will looks like.,

```
var dataToStore = JSON.stringify(data);
localStorage.setItem('someData', dataToStore);
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Felix that it is better to store the value in json string.. 
but just to answer your question.

```
var text = [];
for(var i = 0; i < data.category; i++){
    var car = data.category[i];
    text.push(car.id, car.name);
}
localStorage.setItem('carList', text.join(','));
```